# How can I force Blogger's 'search widget' to use HTTPS?

Tags: https, blogger, cloudflare

I've just set up CloudFlare for my website, so that I can run HTTPS (yes, I know it's not encrypted end-to-end... this is fine). All the images, script resources, etc. are now linked using protocol-agnostic URLs, but I'm still not getting the green 'Secure' indicator in Chrome's address bar.

This is because Blogger is injecting their nav/header bar into my pages, and that bar includes a search form with an `action` attribute of "http://www.example.com/" (no HTTPS)

I can't use CloudFlare to rewrite it because it's not being served from my own host. I've tried hiding it using CSS but this doesn't remove the warning. There's no explicit option I can find anywhere in the Blogger admin to configure or remove this header/search bar.

It's a fragment of HTML inside an IFRAME; before I start hacking around with all sorts of complicated JavaScript to try and intercept the iframe and stop it loading, is there a cleaner way of doing this? I'm happy with the search form targetting https://, I'm happy to remove the search form - or even the entire nav bar - from the page; I just want to get rid of the mixed-mode security messages and get my green padlock... any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

...and, of course, within 2 minutes of posting the question, I've found it.

Log into Blogger, Layout, Navbar, Edit, and there's an option to switch the navbar off.

D'oh.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! It is the way. You can struggle for days and days and finally in desperation and frustration you post a question and Wha La! You find the answer! It happens to all of us. Cheers!!